# What are these patterns in this Backbone TodoMVC example

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, iife

Looking into the [todomvc backbone codes example](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/backbone).
The structure in the js/ fold:

```
├── app.js
├── collections
│   └── todos.js
├── models
│   └── todo.js
├── routers
│   └── router.js
└── views
    ├── app-view.js
    └── todo-view.js
```

app.js

```
var app = app || {};
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // kick things off by creating the `App`
    new app.AppView();
});
```

collections/todos.js

```
var app = app || {};

(function () {
    'use strict';
    var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Todo,
    app.todos = new Todos();
})();
```

models/todo.js

```
var app = app || {};

(function () {
    'use strict';
    app.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    });
})();
```

views/app-view.js

```
var app = app || {};
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
})(jQuery);
```

I have two questions:

1. why `var app = app || {}` in each file?
2. What are the differences between `$(function(){})`, `(function(){})()`, and `(function($))(jQuery)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `app` variable is global and encapsulates entire Backbone application to minimize global namespace pollution. [Here](https://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) you can find more details about Namespacing Patterns.

   `var app = app || {}` initializes global `app` variable with new empty object if it is not initialized yet. Otherwise it will be untouched.
2. The functions:

   - `$(function(){})` is a shortcut for jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){})`. [Docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
   - `(function(){})()` is an [Immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) without parameters
   - `(function($){ /* here $ is safe jQuery object */ })(jQuery)` is IIFE with parameter - `jQuery` object will be passed as `$` into that anonymous function

```js
$(function() {
  console.log("Document ready event");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Document ready event");
});

(function() {
  console.log("Immediately-invoked function expression without parameters");
})();

(function($) {
  console.log("Immediately-invoked function expression with parameter. $ is a jQuery object here:");
  console.log($.fn.jquery);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The real name of self-invoking function is IIFE for [_Immediately-invoked function expression_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Comment: Your first point is also incorrect, `var app = app || {}` only serves as a namespace for the app, to avoid polluting the global namespace, but the order is still important as you can't use something that isn't defined yet.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Renamed to IIFE. I used name from w3schools.com

Comment: About first point `app` is actually global and it pollutes the global namespase. In this ToDo example it even is marked with comment `/*global Backbone */` : https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/backbone/js/models/todo.js

Comment: It's more that it limits its polluting to one variable, instead of everything being global.

Comment: Ok, added this note to the answer :)

Comment: Now I'm reading *'JavaScipt Patterns'* book by *Stoyan Stefanov* and he uses `self-invoking` and `self-executing` names for IIFE. I think it's not so important how to call this

Comment: Yeah, you were correct already with self-invoking, I was just pointing out the full name. Most JavaScript developer will refer to IIFE which is the most descriptive name in the JavaScript context.

Answer (score 4):

While [Yurii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40349763/1218980) explained the difference between all the patterns, it's missing the "why" you would need these.

## Namespacing and scoping

The overrall goal of the following patterns is mostly namespacing and scoping, with different benefits. It's a good practice to avoid polluting the global namespace, and since JavaScript doesn't have namespace as a core feature, other patterns have emmerged to solve that.

See [How do I declare a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript).

### Global namespace

```
var app = app || {}; // if it doesn't exist yet, make it an new object.
```

In order to **avoid polluting the global namespace** (AKA making everything a global variable), you create only **one variable**, inside of which you insert every other modules of your app.

Then, each file exports its module into that sole global variable.

*Note that the order of the files is still important if a module depends on another.*

If we look at the [TodoMVC example](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/backbone/index.html), they included the files in a specific order:

```
<script src="js/models/todo.js"></script>
<script src="js/collections/todos.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/todo-view.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/app-view.js"></script>
<script src="js/routers/router.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

### Scoping

Imagine you declared `var test = 2;` in a file and it's a critical variable that is used throughout that module. Then, in another file, you copy the good pattern you were using inside the first module. You've just overriden the `test` variable and now, it is involontary shared between two modules.

In order to have local functions and variables private to a module, you can scope them with an [Immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). [Block scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is relatively new and not well-supported yet, so the safest way is to use the function scope.

```
var app = app || {}; // global

(function () {
    // private to this scope
    var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

    // export the Todos constructor to the global app namespace
    app.Todos = Todos;

    function localFunction(param) { /** snip **/ }
})();
```

Comment: If you use `$(document).ready` to init your JS then order of JS files isn't important because at that moment all files will be downloaded and executed by JS engine. Actually `app.js` inits Backbone app when DOM is ready

Comment: @YuriiSemeniuk only [app.js](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/backbone/js/app.js). The other files are inside IIFE and are executed immediately.

Comment: I've fixed my answer. Thank you

Comment: Since anyway we need to include JS-files in specific order then why not just create some `core.js` file and in it declare the global `app` object, include this file first and omit `var app = app || {}` in every following file?

Comment: @YuriiSemeniuk files without any dependency within your modules (like a Backbone model), may be included in any order but still before they're needed (like before the collection that uses it), that's where the `var app = app || {};` is useful. It also helps linters which don't know about other files by default.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Both answers are good. thanks. I just selected one as answer and up-voted the other.

Comment: @BAE yes, totally fair, Yurii fixed what made me comment, so his answer is good.

Comment: @EmileBergeron an extrq question, here app === window.app?

Comment: @BAE yes, you can inspect the `window` object with the dev tool console and see all the globals