# How to redefine object and communicate object?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I faced some problems, I know `var app = app || {}` means creating variable **app** is empty object then **app** is used through redefining activity.

But i don't understand how to use the empty object in backbone like above method.

**Router.js**

```
 var app = app || {};
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var views = app.view = app.view || {};
    app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'list/:id': 'listRoute',
            'situation': 'situationRoute',
            'culture': 'cultureRoute',
            'level': 'livingwordsRoute',
            //wildcard place on last.
            '*home': 'homeRoute'
        },
        _bindRoutes: function() {
          if (!this.routes) return;
          this.routes = _.result(this, 'routes');
          var route, routes = _.keys(this.routes);
          while ((route = routes.pop()) != null) {
            this.route(route, this.routes[route]);
          }
        },
        initialize: function() {
            // create the layout once here
            this.layout = new views.Application({
                el: 'body',
            });
        },
        homeRoute: function() {
            var view = new views.Home();
            var target = 'home';
            this.layout.setContent(view, target);
        },
        situationRoute: function() {
            var view = new views.Situation();
            var target = 'situation';
            this.layout.setContent(view, target);
        },
        listRoute: function(id) {
            switch (id) {
              case 1:
                var list = new app.collection([
                    {
                      id : "1",
                      url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01718.mp4",
                      imgSrc : "assets/img/call/1_thumbnail.png",
                      title: "call situation conservation"
                    },
                    {
                      id : "2",
                      url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01722.mp4",
                      imgSrc : "assets/img/call/2_thumbnail.png",
                      title: "call situation conservation"
                    }
                  ]);
                break;
              default:
              var list = new app.collection([
                  {
                    id : "1",
                    url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01718.mp4",
                    imgSrc : "assets/img/call/1_thumbnail.png",
                    title: "call situation conservation"
                  },
                  {
                    id : "2",
                    url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01722.mp4",
                    imgSrc : "assets/img/call/2_thumbnail.png",
                    title: "call situation conservation"
                  }
                ]);
            }
            var view = new views.list();
            var target = 'list';
            this.layout.setContent(view, target);
        },
        cultureRoute: function(){
            var view = new views.Culture();
            var target = 'culture';
            this.layout.setContent(view, target);
        },
        livingwordsRoute: function(){
            var view = new views.Level();
            var target = 'livingwords';
            this.layout.setContent(view, target);
        }
      });
      var router = new app.Router();
      Backbone.history.start();
})();
```

**VideoList.js**

```
    var app = app || {};
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var models = app.model = app.model || {};
    var collections = app.collection = app.collection || {};
    models.Video = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            console.log('model create');
        },
        defaults:{
                 id : "1",
                 url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01718.mp4",
                 imgSrc : "assets/img/call/1_thumbnail.png",
                 title: "call situation conservation"
        }
    });
    collections.VideoLists =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: models.Video
    });
    var lists = new collections.VideoLists([
        {
            id : "1",
            url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01718.mp4",
            imgSrc : "assets/img/call/1_thumbnail.png",
            title: "call situation conservation"
        },
        {
            id : "2",
            url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01722.mp4",
            imgSrc : "assets/img/call/2_thumbnail.png",
            title: "call situation conservation"
        }
    ]);
    console.log(lists);
})();
```

**view.js**

```
    var app = app || {};
(function() {
    'use strict';
    //views linitalize
    var views = app.view = app.view || {};
    views.Application = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
           this.$content = this.$('#main');
            //this.$loading = this.$('#loading');
        },
        setContent: function(view, target) {
            var content = this.content;
            var subUrl = this.target;

            if (content) content.remove();

            content = this.content = view;
            subUrl = this.target = target;

            var templateName = subUrl;
            var tmpl_dir = '../assets/static';
            var tmpl_url = tmpl_dir + '/' + templateName + '.html';
            var tmpl_string = '';

            $.ajax({
                url: tmpl_url,
                method: 'GET',
                async: false,
                dataType : 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    tmpl_string = data;
                }
            });
            this.$content.html(content.render(tmpl_string).el);
        }
    });
    views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
        //how to get return result? in parent object?
    });
    views.Situation = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
    });
    views.list = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new app.collection();
      },
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
    });
    views.Culture = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
    });
    views.Level = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
    });
})();
```

**list.html**

```
  <script type="text/template" id="list-template">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="<%= list.url %>"></a>
        <figure id="<%= list.id %>">
          <img src="<%= list.imgSrc %>" alt="">
          <figcaption><%= list.title%></figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      </script>
```

This is my source.

i want to communicate between Router and View because i don't understand why indicate

> app.collcetion is not constructor

and then, i tested in the videolist.js

```
var lists = new collections.VideoLists([
        {
            id : "1",
            url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01718.mp4",
            imgSrc : "assets/img/call/1_thumbnail.png",
            title: "call situation conservation"
        },
        {
            id : "2",
            url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01722.mp4",
            imgSrc : "assets/img/call/2_thumbnail.png",
            title: "call situation conservation"
        }
    ]);
```

is great generated. (in the videoList.js) 
see the below screentshot.

[image]

and i want to know how to refactor repeated code.

please refer to my below source 
  
**router.js**

```
views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
        //how to get return result? in parent object?
    });
    views.Situation = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
    });
    views.list = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new app.collection();
      },
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
    });
    views.Culture = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
    });
    views.Level = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
    });
```

**view.js**

```
 views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
    });
    views.Situation = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      }
    });
```

I don't want to repeat same object and source.

How can I change them?

Comment: Nobody's going to read through all that.  Consult the following http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're asking 2 different questions, you should create a new one specific to the _refactor_ part.

Comment: after few time, i will be writing question that is devided topic and i better writing in case of writing question thanks to your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var app = app || {};` technique is just a namespacing pattern to avoid polluting the global namespace.

[More details on this namespacing pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350459/1218980)

A single global variable named `app` is created, then the code for the app is added to it. When splitting the app in multiple files, you want to be able to use the `app` variable if it was defined previously.

Enters the `app || {}` trick which will return the `app` variable if it's truthy or the `{}` empty object if `app` is falsy (probably `undefined`).

Though this technique enables different ordering of the files, if a file requires another component (like `app.collection`), the files should be ordered accordingly.

```
<script src="collections.js"></script><!-- defines app.collection -->
<script src="views.js"></script><!-- requires app.collection -->
```

[How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript)

---

Regarding refactoring, first take a look at [how to use `_.template`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148034/1218980), depending on the version of Underscore you're using, it might not work as you expect.

Then, for the repeating `render` function, it's totally normal to have those. They look similar, but will become much different over the development process.

Comment: You have always answered my questions kindly, so i'm appreciated so much. Some of my questions were solved, but some problems are remained. I will give the problems. Can you solve those things? I always thank you. Sincerely