# How to create collection through global variable in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am sent the assistance by many advisors in stackoverflow, In part of my problem is solved but a few problems are remained.

I consult the answer and I has try to solve the problem as a result from it  i understood the javascript namespacing pattren.

[A namespacing pattern to avoid polluting the global namespace.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42254128/7250379)
[More details on this namespacing pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350459/7250379)
[How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947280/7250379)

I suffer from problem that global variable is created successfully however, i don't handle the generated variable.

**collecton.js**

```
    var app = app || {};
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var collections = app.Collection = app.Collection || {};

    collections.VideoLists =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: app.Model,
        initialize: function(){
            console.log('load Collection');
        }
    });

    app.Collection = collections.VideoLists;
})();
```

**model.js**

```
var app = app || {};
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var models = app.Model = app.Model || {};

    models.Video = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            console.log('model create');
        },
        defaults:{
                 id : "1",
                 url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01718.mp4",
                 imgSrc : "assets/img/call/1_thumbnail.png",
                 title: "call situation conservation"
        }
    });
  app.Model = new models.Video();
})();
```

**router.js**

```
listRoute: function(id) {
          //generate the collection using the listsection
          var videoList = this.collection;
          var getId = parseInt(id);
            switch (getId) {
              case 1:
                new videoList([
                    {
                      id : "1",
                      url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01718.mp4",
                      imgSrc : "assets/img/call/1_thumbnail.png",
                      title: "call situation conservation"
                    },
                    {
                      id : "2",
                      url : "/assets/videos/call/MOV01722.mp4",
                      imgSrc : "assets/img/call/2_thumbnail.png",
                      title: "call situation conservation"
                    }
                  ]);
                break;

  //app.router init part
  initialize: function() {
            // create the layout once here
            this.layout = new views.Application({
                el: 'body',
            });
            // create model and collection once here
            this.model = app.Model;
            this.collection = app.Collection;
        }
```

**Please see the below picture**
[image]

I think the generation has been done properly.
But I do not understand why I get this error.

I tried at first
1. Don't generate collection with `new function` (as current my source)
2. Create variable `videoList` as Object.
3. Stores `Collection` in a variable.
4. Use collection.create function.
   For example, `list.create({id:'dasdsad'});`

However, this attempt eventually yielded the same result.
How can i solve them?

Comment: are you including the *collection.js* before the *model.js* script? stick a breakpoint in the *collection.js* and ensure that `app.Model` is defined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## What's the purpose of the namespacing pattern?

You are misusing the namespace pattern. The goal in this case is to namespace all your custom Backbone classes constructor into the `app` object.

In order to keep everything clearly separated, put all your collections constructor into the `app.Collection` object, models constructor within `app.Model`, etc.

If you inspect the `app` namespace after all the classes are created, it should look like the following:

```
var app = {
    Collection: {
        VideoList: /* video list constructor */
    },
    Model: {
        Video: /* video model constructor */
    },
    View: {
        /* same thing goes for views */
    }
};
```

The `app` namespace *shouldn't<sup>1</sup>* contain instances, mainly constructors.

Do not overwrite the constructors references:

```
app.Model = new models.Video();
```

Create an instance when you need one only, and keep it in the scope it's needed.

```
this.model = new app.Model.Video();
this.collection = app.Collection.VideoList();
```

## Instances and constructors

To really understand the previous point, you need to understand the differences between a constructor and an instance. The concept is applicable to other OOP languages, but I'll keep the description within the JavaScript language specifics.

A constructor is just a function. From the [MDN doc on `Object.prototype.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor):

> All objects will have a `constructor` property.
>
> [...]
>
> The following example creates a prototype, `Tree`, and an object of that
>   type, `theTree`.
>
> ```
> function Tree(name) {
>   this.name = name;
> }
>
> var theTree = new Tree('Redwood');
> ```

As seen in the previous example, to create an instance, use the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1218980)

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or
>   of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.
>
> ```
> new constructor[([arguments])]
> ```

Creating custom constructors lets you define custom types (classes). There are multiple ways to create more complex custom types in JavaScript but that's another discussion. For more details, see [How to “properly” create a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1595611/1218980)

Fortunately, Backbone provides an easy (opinionated) way to define new types, the [`extend` function](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/bd50e2e4a4af5c09bc490185aab215794d42258b/backbone.js#L1978-L2007), which is [available on all the Backbone's base types](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/bd50e2e4a4af5c09bc490185aab215794d42258b/backbone.js#L2010).

```
var ModelConstructor = Backbone.Model.extend({ /*...*/ });

var modelInstance = new ModelConstructor();
```

Note that `myVariable = MyConstructor` will just pass a reference of the constructor to `myVariable`, it won't create a new instance. You could still use the variable as the constructor though.

```
var myInstance = new myVariable();
```

## Ordering and dependencies

If you look at your code, you'll notice that the `app.Collection.VideoList` class uses the `app.Model.Video` as the value for the `model` property.

This means that `app.Collection.VideoList` depends on the availability of the `app.Model.Video` class. So the collection file should be inserted into the document after the model file.

Like in [the other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350459/1218980) you linked:

```
<script src="js/models/todo.js"></script><!-- no dependencies -->
<script src="js/collections/todos.js"></script><!-- depends on the model -->
<script src="js/views/todo-view.js"></script><!-- depends on the collection and the model -->
<script src="js/views/app-view.js"></script><!-- depends on the todo-view -->
<script src="js/routers/router.js"></script><!-- depends on the app view -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script><!-- depends on the router -->
```

---

*<sup>1. The `app` namespace object could contain an instance of an object if you want to share it between all your app, like a singleton, or a namespaced global, or a service.</sup>*