# browser returns an error: app is not defined

Tags: javascript, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I have an app running on Backbone in front-end and when a browser loads a page it returns an error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined
    at index.js:6
    at index.js:51
(anonymous) @ index.js:6
(anonymous) @ index.js:51
```

### index.js

```
/* global app:true */

(function() {
  'use strict';

  app = app || {};  // error here although it must prevent of undefined 
                    // variables stay undefined

  //.......
  //backbone code here
  //.......

  $(document).ready(function() {
    app.contactView = new app.ContactView(); //error here
  });
}());
```

Switching from build to CDN or enter into a Backbone.Model properties returns the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Only move the variable outside of the function scope if you want it to be global.

```
/* global app:true */

var app = app || {};

(function() {
  'use strict';

  //.......
  //backbone code here
  //.......

  // you can use the jQuery shortcut version of the document ready.
  $(function() {
    app.contactView = new app.ContactView();
  });
}());
```

Or pass it as a parameter of the [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

```
(function(app) {
  // ...
})(app = app || {});
```

If you have multiple files, they should all implement a similar structure as the examples above to be able to use the `app` namespace.

## Additional information on namespacing

- [How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/881515/1218980)
- [Different common patterns in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40349611/1218980)
- [The purpose of the namespacing pattern with Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42372930/1218980)

Comment: No, these 2 options returned the same error. I have some more files with similar structure, maybe I should change them because it won't be global otherwise?

Comment: @ASem Each file should have the `var app = app || {};` line at the top.

Comment: Changed them all and it helped, thanks! As I understand your first option leaves the global app object accessable but its properties are inside a function scope and it's safe to leave like so.

Comment: @ASem in fact, everything inside `app` is globally accessible since `app` is a global. The function scope let you define local variables that won't leak into the global space. This is useful for private parts of a component, simulating static field for a *class*, etc.